# union of unknown set of xmls

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have set of XML's ( varies between 2 and 6) that needs to be processed(traversed and checked for certain data and relations within) - The XML's have some "Recursive Data"
 here is a simple example involving a test data for explanation - 2 files considered as example

```
      File1.xml:
<some root------standard header not entered for the example----->
<parent>
    <ID>AB-1234</ID>
    <Description>Good book</Description>
    <Date_Created>08-10-2011</Date_Created>
    <child>
          <ID>BC-0001</ID>
          <Description>Nice</Description>
     </child>
</parent>
<parent>
    <ID>BC-0001</ID>
    <Description>Work Together</Description>
    <Date_Created>08-10-2011</Date_Created>
    <child>
          <ID>DC-0011</ID>
          <Description>Happy</Description>
     </child>
</parent>

  File2.xml:
<some root------standard header not entered for the example----->
<parent>
    <ID>DC-0011</ID>
    <Description> book</Description>
    <Date_Created>08-10-2011</Date_Created>
    <child>
          <ID>EF-0001</ID>
          <Description>Nice</Description>
     </child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <ID>EF-0001</ID>
    <Description>Work Together</Description>
    <Date_Created>08-10-2011</Date_Created>
    <child>
          <ID>PQ-0011</ID>
          <Description>Happy</Description>
     </child>
  </parent>
```

code I am using involves 1) loading both the XML files and combining them

```
  XDocument test1doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File1.xml");
  XDocument test2doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File2.xml");
  IEnumerable<XElement> testElist1 = test1doc.decendants("parent");
  IEnumerable<XElement> testElist2 = test2doc.decendants("parent");
  IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo = testElist1.union(testElist2);
```

2) use the testElistcombo to navigate the elements using foreach - 2 foreach loops (one for the parent and second for the child)
3) while traversing use an if condition to check whether parent ID and Child ID are equal.
I am able to build the hierarchy - no problem with that.
I was able to print the hierarchy along with the level value of the hierarchy.by including a counter in each of the foreach loops.
     my output looks like

```
  AB-1234[level-0]
     >>BC-0001[level-1]
         >>DC-0011[level-3] 
                ..... and so on.
```

as i said no problem with that. -

Following is the area where i would like some help:
1) when the number of files increases to more than 2 to a max 6, i am using a union in  the following manner

```
           XDocument test1doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File1.xml");
           XDocument test2doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File2.xml");
           XDocument test3doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File3.xml");
           XDocument test4doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File4.xml");
           XDocument test5doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File5.xml");
           XDocument test6doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\File6.xml");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist1 = test1doc.decendants("parent");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist2 = test2doc.decendants("parent");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist3 = test3doc.decendants("parent");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist4 = test4doc.decendants("parent");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist5 = test5doc.decendants("parent");
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElist6 = test6doc.decendants("parent");

           IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo1 = testElist1.union(testElist2);
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo2 = testElistcombo1.union(testElist3);
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo3 = testElistcombo2.union(testElist4);
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo4 = testElistcombo3.union(testElist5);
           IEnumerable<XElement> testElistcombo5 = testElistcombo4.union(testElist6);
```

and use the testElistcombo5.for processing.
help required: an alternative way to load and combine the XML's to for processing.

2) The process is resource intensive and take a fair bit of time to complete the hierarchy building
help required: is there an alternative way to process the xml's for building hierarchy in Recursive Data.

Comment: Why arent you doing this in a for / foreach loop?

Comment: all this is being done in a foreach loop.i have taken out the code, just to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: you can do this using the [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) function to aggregate the elements for each document into one set of elements:

```
IEnumerable<string> filenames = { "filename1.xml", "filename2.xml" };

IEnumerable<XDocument> documents = filenames.Select(XDocument.Load);
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> documentsElements = documents.Select(document => document.Descendants("parent"));
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = documentsElements.Aggregate((working, next) => working.Union(next));
```

Comment: It will not solve the performance problem: you should profile to work out which part of the code is slowing it down, e.g. document loading, descendent selection, the union or something else entirely (like processing the resultant set of elements).

Comment: currently looking into performance tuning, will post back on the developments.

Comment: Thanks -update: I was able to pin point the reason - it was the loading process. All this time the loading script was running within the foreach loop, upon careful review - and a bit of re-coding -The XML's are now getting processed under 5min.